# How do I autogenerate PHP comments with Eclipse/Aptana?

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

Hey all, is there a way I can have my Eclipse/Aptana auto generate standard PHP header comments as well as insert my subversion version string? Im trying to do it for phpDoc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Eclipse cannot do this. For my needs I switched to Komodo Edit.